# vba: Find function with .rows returning an unexpected result

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am trying to use the find function to make a wider code applicable to multiple instances of the same basic table. I look for table headers to the left of my table with this code

```
preschoolStart = (Sheets("Rotas").Columns(3).Find(What:="School starters", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row) + 1
```

which finds the header "School starters" and sends the reference to the cell below it which contain the first of several names in the category "preschool".

This works in the instance above and in two other instances with the same format but when used for the below case it returns a row value far below the expected.

```
staffStart = (Columns(3).Find(What:="Staff", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row) + 1
```

My original theory as to why this could be was that there are other headers with staff in the name which is confusing things but that would have been fixed with the changes made on the advice of @Jeeped and @Rory.

[Preschoolers section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VnqY.png)
[Staff section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnjFf.png)

Note: The actual problem was that I was inadvertently writing something different into the same cell and hadn't thought to check the staffStart variable a different way. I have therefore decided to make the answer from @Jeeped the official answer.

Comment: Are there other rows in column C that contain "Staff"? Specifically look at the row one up from `staffStart` in column C.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of the 2 tables. Also posting your code might help to understand the issue as the problem might not be on the line you specified

Comment: @Rory There are cells that contain "Total staff", including the one above the staffStart result. However, there is another with the "Total staff" between the expected and actual result rows. There is also "Staff" further down in the table.

Comment: Your search isn't looking at partial matches, but could certainly return the 'Staff' entry further down. If your "Staff" header is in C1 and C18 also had "Staff", your code would return 19, not 2.

Comment: That makes sense but that doesn't seem to be what's happening. It's returning 115 rather than 96.

Comment: @Zac The only other code referencing staffStart is where I write it to a hidden sheet to use later and in the main body (which I will replace with reading from the hidden cell once I've sorted this problem). This is how I'm writing to the cell `Sheets("Hidden").cells(2, staffStartClm) = staffStart`.

Comment: What is in C114 on the sheet that is active when you run that code? (assuming the code is in a normal module, not a worksheet module)

Comment: @Rory The code is in a worksheet module, could that be a problem (Currently teaching myself vba)? In answer to your question, the code is triggered by changes to the number of rows so C114 will either be "Total staff" or empty (staffStart still comes out as 115 though).

Comment: In a worksheet code module, the search is done *on that sheet*, regardless of which sheet is active because you didn't specify a sheet. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet reference properly and add an `After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)` parameter to the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

```
with Sheets("Rotas").Columns(3)
    staffStart = .Find(What:="Staff", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
end with
```

Comment: Annoyingly this doesn't seem to have worked. What is the additional parameter doing?